# Missing properties in spring-configuration-metadata.json when configuring a list of third party pojos?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

How can I get a correctly generated `spring-configuration-metadata.json` when I try to externalize configuration of a list of third party pojos in Spring Boot using `@ConfigurationProperties`? Put it differently, how can I make tab completion work in `application.properties` for these pojos?

Given an external class that I cannot change (it is included as a third party dependency):

*HostConfig*

```java
public class HostConfig {

    private String name;
    private int port;

    // more properties, getters and setters
}
```

I have added some config in my test properties file:

*application-test.properties*

```
host.configs[0].name=first-host
host.configs[0].port=1111

host.configs[1].name=second-host
host.configs[1].port=2222
```

Finally, I would like to be able to autowire a `List<HostConfig>` to other Spring beans. For this reason, I have created the `HostConfigProperties` as a static class in my `AppConfig` class:

*AppConfig*

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "host")
    static class HostConfigProperties {
        private List<HostConfig> configs;

        void setConfigs(List<HostConfig> configs) {
            this.configs = configs;
        }

        @Bean(name = "hostConfigs")
        List<HostConfig> getConfigs() {
            return configs;
        }
    }

}
```

This works and my test passes successfully:

*AppConfigTest*

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class AppConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    List<HostConfig> hostConfigs;

    @Test
    void createsHostConfigs() {
        HostConfig firstHostConfig = hostConfigs.get(0);
        assertThat(firstHostConfig.getName(), is("first-host"));
        assertThat(firstHostConfig.getPort(), is(1111));

        HostConfig secondHostConfig = hostConfigs.get(1);
        assertThat(secondHostConfig.getName(), is("second-host"));
        assertThat(secondHostConfig.getPort(), is(2222));
    }

}
```

However,  the `properties` section of the generated `spring-configuration-metadata.json` is empty (see below), meaning that the IDE-support for tab completion is not working for neither `host.configs.name` nor `host.configs.port` when editing `application.properties`:

*spring-configuration-metadata.json*

```json
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "host",
      "type": "com.example.service.AppConfig$HostConfigProperties",
      "sourceType": "com.example.service.AppConfig$HostConfigProperties"
    },
  ],
  "properties": [],
  "hints": []
}
```

Dependencies:

```xml
    <!-- copied from pom.xml -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- more Maven config -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

---

Related: when working with a singular external bean (see below), the `spring-configuration-metadata.json` is generated correctly:

*OtherConfig*

```java
public class OtherConfig {

    private int timeout;

    public int getTimeout() {
        return this.timeout;
    }

    public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
}
```

*AppConfig*

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "other")
    OtherConfig otherConfig() {
        return new OtherConfig();
    }
}
```

*application-test.properties*

```
other.timeout=1000
```

*AppConfigTest*

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public AppConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    OtherConfig otherConfig;

    @Test
    void createsOtherConfigs() {
        assertThat(otherConfig.getTimeout(), is(1_000));
    }
}
```

*spring-configuration-metadata.json*

```json
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "other",
      "type": "com.example.service.OtherConfig",
      "sourceType": "com.example.service.AppConfig",
      "sourceMethod": "otherConfig()"
    },
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "other.timeout",
      "type": "java.lang.Integer",
      "sourceType": "com.example.service.OtherConfig"
    },
  ],
  "hints": []
}
```